# RESTful authentication without oAuth

Tags: php, rest, oauth

I am currently implementing a RESTful service on an IIS/PHP5.4 environment.

While looking for the best-practice method to implement authentication most people/blogs/forums/stackoverflow answers point towards using oAuth for authentication.

unfortunately there is currently no mod_oauth module available for PHP5.4 on windows.

So my question: what is the best method/best practice to implement a secure authentication system for a RESTful service without using oAuth.

Alternatively: if anyone knows of a full featured oAuth class that pretty much implements the methods from mod_oauth in a standalone way, that info would also be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there a PECL extension?  I see [requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.requirements.php) state: "PECL/oauth requires PHP 5.1 or newer, ext/hash and ext/pcre."  As for what you should use ultimately depends on your requirements.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately windows can not handle uncompiled extensions. It can't compile the pecl extensions. So unless there is a prepared binary, I can't use it.

Comment: [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.3/) or [C++ 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20682) but the extension looks to be for 5.3 only... Not sure.  Anyway probably overkill for what you need.  Check any [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Authentication) pages if your just wondering about some 'best practices'?

Comment: You can do HTTP Auth completely within PHP, so you don't have to use Apache password files and/or sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `hash_hmac` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) to encrypt all the submitted dat to a hash using a private key that both my server and client knew. If anyone tinkers with the information in either way (url/post data) the signature will not match the server generated version anymore, which will cause the request to fail.